# Alternatives to view log on android device

Tags: android

what alternatives are there to see the log of logcat on android device ?

I think maybe I could see the log file in an android console as the tail of linux, or maybe there is any graphical application which redirect the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Log Viewer (logcat)" is available in the PlayStore

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite wure what you are after. If you dont like the logcat view of your IDE you can use

```
adb logcat
```

To get the output in the same way as tail on linux.